# How does Hive stores data and what is SerDe?

Tags: hadoop, hive

when querying a table, a SerDe will **deserialize a row of data from the bytes in the file to objects used internally by Hive to operate on that row of data**. when performing an INSERT or CTAS (see “Importing Data” on page 441), the table’s SerDe will **serialize Hive’s internal representation of a row of data into the bytes that are written to the output file**.

1. Is serDe library?
2. How does hive store data i.e it stores in file or table?
3. Please can anyone explain the bold sentences clearly? 
   I'm new to hive!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Answers

1. Yes, SerDe is a Library which is built-in to the Hadoop API
2. Hive uses Files systems like HDFS or any other storage (FTP) to store data, data here is in the form of tables (which has rows and columns).
3. SerDe - Serializer, Deserializer instructs hive on how to process a record (Row). Hive enables semi-structured (XML, Email, etc) or unstructured records (Audio, Video, etc) to be processed also. For Example If you have 1000 GB worth of RSS Feeds (RSS XMLs). You can ingest those to a location in HDFS. You would need to write a custom SerDe based on your XML structure so that Hive knows how to load XML files to Hive tables or other way around.

For more information on how to write a SerDe read this [post](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/12/how-to-use-a-serde-in-apache-hive/)

Comment: So serDe will (Deserialize)convert bytes of data from a file which on HDFS to a object in order to store it on Hive table.   Hdfs(File)----Deserialize---->(tables)Hive.  Am i right?

Comment: There is no 2 storages in hive, Hives store is the actual files in HDFS. SerDe will Deserialize data from file to a object so that it can be queried in using SQL SELECT like syntax. and more data can be added into those files using SQL INSERT like syntax. The only store is files which reside in HDFS for Hive.

Comment: hi shazin, You mean to say that without SerDe you can't query Hive tables. Hive stores data in files(tables) on HDFS and SerDe(Deserialization) comes into picture when you query data and when you want to insert more data SerDe(Serializaton) is used.

Comment: Yes, currently this SerDes are used by Hive by default MetadataTypedColumnsetSerDe which is for CSV delimited files.

Answer (score 10):

In this aspect we can see Hive as some kind of database engine. This engine is working on tables which are built from **records**. 
When we let Hive (as well as any other database) to work in its own internal formats - we do not care. 
When we want Hive to process our own files as tables (external tables) we have to let him know - how to translate data in files into records. This is exactly the role of SerDe. You can see it as plug-in which enables Hive to read / write your data. 
For example - you want to work with CSV. Here is example of CSV_Serde
https://github.com/ogrodnek/csv-serde/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bizo/hive/serde/csv/CSVSerde.java
Method serialize will read the data, and chop it into fields assuming it is CSV 
Method deserialize will take a record and format it as CSV.

Comment: Thank You David. Can u give me more detail on how database engine works, particularly hive. Any blog or pdf?

Comment: I do not know one good source, If you will hint the area I might be able to help. As a starting point - I would suggest reading about MySQL and it's pluggable engines. IMHO it is DB engine with one of more transparent architectures. Regarding hive - you can ask specific questions, I might know.

Answer (score 1):

Hive can analyse semi structured and unstructured data as well by using
(1) complex data type(struct,array,unions)
(2) By using SerDe

SerDe interface allow us to instruct hive as to how the record should be processed. Serializer will take java object that hive has been working on,and convert it into something that hive can store and Deserializer take binary representation of a record and translate into java object that hive can manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

I think the above has the concepts serialise and deserialise back to front. Serialise is done on write, the structured data is serialised into a bit/byte stream for storage. On read, the data is deserialised from the bit/byte storage format to the structure required by the reader. eg Hive needs structures that look like rows and columns but hdfs stores the data in bit/byte blocks, so serialise on write, deserialise on read.