# what is the use of serde in HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive, external-tables

Hi I'm beginner to hive and I found the below from one of the sample code, can some one help me in understanding the below piece of code :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE emp (
  id bigint,
name string, 
dept bigint,
  salary bigint)
partitioned by (yearofjoining string) 
       ROW FORMAT SERDE 
          'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
        WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
          'field.delim'='|', 
          'serialization.format'='|') 
        STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
          'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
        OUTPUTFORMAT 
          'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
        LOCATION
          's3n://xxx/xxxx/xxx/xxx/xx'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Hive stores data and what is SerDe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605640/how-does-hive-stores-data-and-what-is-serde)